# Unresolved external symbols LNK2019 when copying and pasting project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, unresolved-external

I'm attempting to submit some of my coursework, which involves me zipping up the project. However whenever I copy and paste (or zip) my project, it no longer works in the copied version (original works perfectly). I can't for the life of me figure out why. These are the errors and warnings I get that I don't receive when running the original:
[image].

My project contains 7 files and no external libraries or anything which confuses me even more. I'm also using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the pathing is correct?  Does the project properties still point to where they should?

Comment: Sorry where exactly am i looking and what should they be pointing to? Fairly new to this sorta.

Comment: Look in the project properties.

Comment: Right but where exactly? There are a lot of properties to look at.